# How to add two numbers in simple DOM exercise

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add 2 numbers and make the result appear in the body of the page. I took out HTML code on purpose just to make it easier to view. It's the JS that is giving me a headache.

Any ideas?

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById('item1');
let input2 = document.getElementById('item2');
let button = document.querySelector('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  let firstNumber = input1.value;
  input1.value = '';
  let secondNumber = input2.value;
  input2.value = '';

  // Here I am clueless

  input1.focus();
  input2.focus();
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <label for="item">Enter a number in each field:</label>
  <input type="text" id="item1">
  <input type="text" id="item2">
  <button>Add numbers</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for any advice. cheers

Comment: immanuel use `innerText` or `innerHtml` to write to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

To write to the page, use `innerHtml` or `innerText`
Also values returned from `inputs` are strings not numbers. You can simply convert them to numbers by prefixing a plus e.g `+input1.value`

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById('item1');
let input2 = document.getElementById('item2');
let button = document.querySelector('button');



button.onclick = function() {
  //write the results to page 
 
  
  let firstNumber = input1.value;
  input1.value = '';
  let secondNumber = input2.value;
  input2.value = '';


  // Here I am clueless
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML  = 'Result:  '+ (+firstNumber  + +secondNumber);

  input1.focus();
  input2.focus();

}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<div>
  <label for="item">Enter a number in each field:</label>
  <input type="text" id="item1">
  <input type="text" id="item2">
  <button onclick="calculate()">Add numbers</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Explaination for *'Result:  '+ (+firstNumber  + +secondNumber);***

In this statement, we have used `+` at following three places with following functions:

1.`'Result:  '`**+** `(+firstNumber  + +secondNumber);`
This is used to concatenate/join strings in JS. i.e Result: & sum of the inputs are joined in this case making `Result: 3`

2.`'Result:  '+ (`**+**`firstNumber  +` **+**`secondNumber);`
These two pluses are used to convert a string to number. E.g if `firstNumber` is `"1"` (string with quotes) then using a plus like `+firstNumber` will convert it to `1` (number with no quotes). It's important to do this conversion because otherwise you will get `"1"+"2"` = `"12"` instead of `1+2` = `3`

3.`'Result:  '+ (+firstNumber` **+** `+secondNumber);`
The third plus is for simple mathematic addition of `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`

Comment: Ok that was great! In the alert your code is +(+input1.value + +input2.value)); I have never seen that before. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks & Sure thing @ImmanuelJaeggi Please check the updated answer for explanation  of all the pluses used :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to convert your inputs to the proper type. html inputs returns strings and you want integers.

```
let firstNumber = parseInt(input1.value);
let secondNumber = parseInt(input2.value);
```

Then sum them

```
let sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
```

And finally add the result to the HTML body

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sum));
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I have to add more to this code to get the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a result area in tor form of a list and keep a history of the results.

You can create a new list item for each submission.

```js
const input1  = document.getElementById('item1');
const input2  = document.getElementById('item2');
const button  = document.querySelector('button');
const results = document.querySelector('.results');

button.onclick = (e) => {
  const num1 = parseInt(input1.value, 10);
  input1.value = '';
  const num2 = parseInt(input2.value, 10);
  input2.value = '';

  // Here I am clueless
  const element = document.createElement('li');
  element.textContent = `${num1} + ${num2} = ${num1 + num2}`;
  results.append(element);

  input1.focus();
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <label for="item">Enter a number in each field:</label>
  <input type="text" id="item1">
  <input type="text" id="item2">
  <button>Add numbers</button>
</div>
<h2>Results</h2>
<ul class="results">
</ul>
```

Here is a more concise version:

```js
const
  args    = document.querySelectorAll('.arg'),
  btn     = document.querySelector('button'),
  results = document.querySelector('.results');

const getAndReset = (input) => {
  const value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  input.value = '';
  return value;
};

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const
    values = [...args].map(getAndReset),
    result = values.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0),
    element = document.createElement('li');
  
  element.textContent = `${values.join(' + ')} = ${result}`;
  results.append(element);

  args[0].focus();
});
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <label for="item">Enter a number in each field:</label>
  <input type="number" class="arg" />
  <input type="number" class="arg" />
  <button>Add numbers</button>
</div>
<h2>Results</h2>
<ul class="results">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById('item1');
let input2 = document.getElementById('item2');
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.getElementById("result");

function calculate() {
  sum = +input1.value + +input2.value;
  result.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div>
  <label for="item">Enter a number in each field:</label>
  <input type="text" id="item1">
  <input type="text" id="item2">
  <p>Result: <span id="result"></span> </p>
  <button onclick="calculate()">Add numbers</button>
</div>
```